# Replace badly formatted time data in a csv

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to reformat some data in a CSV file that contains data about horse racing.  The problem i have is that the timestamp for the race doesnt follow any normal convention in that it doesnt recognise AM/PM (because all races in the UK take place between 11am and 10pm)

So a timestamp if 11.55 is always AM, and one of 1.15 is always PM (13:15)

I'm trying to update them all into 24 hour format to move data from one software package to another

So i can read in the CSV, do some other replaces no probelm but just cant get my head round the time element.  I had tried a hashtable but I'm struggling to get it to replace any data.

here is some code

```
$a = (get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

$timelist= @{
'1:00'='13:00'
'1:05'='13:05'
'1:10'='13:10'
'1:15'='13:15'
'1:20'='13:20'
'1:25'='13:25'
'1:30'='13:30'  etc all the way to 10:55

foreach ($file in $infiles){ 
$folder = Split-Path $file -Parent
$name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
$outfile = $folder+"\"+"$name"+".csv"

$csv = import-csv $file -delimiter "`t" | Select @{ name='Date' ;Expression={$a}},RaceTime,Track,Horse

    foreach ($row in $csv){
        $row.Horse = $row.Horse.Substring(0, $row.Horse.IndexOf(' ('))
        $row.Track = $row.Track.Substring(0, $row.Track.IndexOf(' ('))
        $row.RaceTime.Value = $timelist[$row.RaceTime]
                    }

            $csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | 
                Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
                Set-Content $outfile
```

The output file doesn't change the time stamps at all.

EDIT: to include input sample data

```
RaceTime    Track   RaceType    RaceClass   Horse   Odds    Jockey  Trainer Placing 
"2.15"  "Cartmel"   "Novices Hurdle"    "Class 4"   "Grapevine (IRE)"   "2.25"  "Brace, Connor" "Leech, Mrs S"  "4th"
"2.50"  "Cartmel"   "Handicap Hurdle"   "Class 4"   "Bannixtown Glory (IRE)"    "3.00"  "Hughes, Brian" "McCain Jnr, D" "3rd"
"3.25"  "Cartmel"   "Novices Chase" "Class 4"   "Francky Du Berlais (FR)"   "2.75"  "Bowen, Mr J C" "Bowen, P"  "3rd"
"4.00"  "Cartmel"   "Handicap Chase"    "Class 5"   "Mash Potato (IRE)" "3.25"  "Bowen, Mr S P" "Kelly, Noel C" "1st"
"4.35"  "Cartmel"   "Handicap Chase"    "Class 4"   "Day Of Roses (IRE)"    "3.50"  "Hughes, Brian" "Foster, Miss J E"  "3rd"
"5.10"  "Cartmel"   "Handicap Hurdle"   "Class 3"   "Cardigan Bay (FR)" "9.00"  "Coleman, A"    "Longsdon, C E" "7th"
"5.45"  "Cartmel"   "Handicap Hurdle"   "Class 4"   "Cape Hideaway" "2.50"  "Galligan, Mr M"    "Vaughan, Tim"  "2nd"
"2.00"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap Nursery"  "Class 6"   "Luna Wish" "2.75"  "Quinn, Jimmy"  "Margarson, G G"    "1st"
"2.35"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap Nursery"  "Class 4"   "Dandizette (IRE)"  "3.75"  "Coughlan, Laura"   "Nicholls, Adrian"  "5th"
"3.10"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap"  "Class 3"   "Emenem"    "5.00"  "Williams, Levi"    "Dow, S"    "3rd"
"3.45"  "Chelmsford City"   "Novices"   "Class 4"   "Strelka"   "3.25"  "Steward, Louis"    "Beckett, R M"  "2nd"
"4.20"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap"  "Class 5"   "Bayston Hill"  "7.00"  "Marsh, Finley" "Usher, M D I"  "2nd"
"4.20"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap"  "Class 5"   "Dangerous Ends"    "6.00"  "Carver, William"   "Johnson, B R"  "9th"
"4.50"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap"  "Class 4"   "Attainment"    "3.00"  "Haynes, Joey"  "Tate, James"   "1st"
"5.25"  "Chelmsford City"   "Handicap"  "Class 6"   "Magicinthemaking (USA)"    "5.00"  "ONeill, K T"   "Long, J E" "2nd"
```

Comment: You need to check all of your variables and find out where the issue is. Is the value changed in `$csv` at all?

Comment: no outputting $csv to the console gives the following

Comment: "Date","RaceTime","Track","Horse"
"25/08/2019","2.15","Cartmel","Grapevine"
"25/08/2019","2.50","Cartmel","Bannixtown Glory"
"25/08/2019","3.25","Cartmel","Francky Du Berlais"
"25/08/2019","4.00","Cartmel","Mash Potato"
"25/08/2019","4.35","Cartmel","Day Of Roses"
"25/08/2019","5.10","Cartmel","Cardigan Bay"

Comment: You're going to have to add samples - I don't know if that file is any different. If it's no different then it looks to me like you don't actually have times in the file

Comment: @ChrisLewis Get-Date expects a colon betwen hour and minute, not a period. Use `Get-Date ($row.RaceTime -replace '\.',':')` to make my answer work.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid sample added of the input tab seperated data

Comment: @Tomalak thanks!  I've been pulling my hair out about this all day!  If you edit you answer I'll mark it up, thanks again

Comment: Done. Always include sample data in any future questions, these things really cannot be guessed by anyone.

Comment: Yes will do.  Its not gone un-noticed that the same issue is probably what was stopping the hashtable working too!

But i like yours better, its cleaner for one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch the conversion table in favor of a little date arithmetic:

```
$today = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"

foreach ($file in $infiles) { 
    $folder = Split-Path $file -Parent
    $name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $outfile = Join-Path $folder "$name.csv"

    $csv = Import-Csv $file -delimiter "`t" | Select-Object @{n='Date';e={$today}},RaceTime,Track,Horse

    foreach ($row in $csv) {
        $row.Horse = ($row.Horse -split ' \(')[0]
        $row.Track = ($row.Track -split ' \(')[0]
        $RaceTime = Get-Date ($row.RaceTime -replace '\.',':')  # Get-Date expects a colon
        if ($RaceTime.Hour -lt 11) { $RaceTime = $RaceTime.AddHours(12) }
        $row.RaceTime = Get-Date $RaceTime -Format "HH:mm"
    }

    $csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $outfile 
}
```

You could also think about dropping the separate `Date` column in the result CSV and formatting `RaceTime` as a full date right-away.

Comment: Thanks, The maths doesnt work because the line

$RaceTime = Get-Date $row.RaceTime

doesnt correctly pick up the times from the column.

Nice idea about the date but the receiving software package requires them to be seperate

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing an input sample - please add one  to your question. It worked with the test data I made up based on your description.

Comment: Thanks, i have included some in the original post